# How to listen to changes on mock service with Jasmine in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to change the return value of a method in my mock service, but the new method is never called.

**The code:**

```
describe('Test 1', function() {
  var ctrl, scope, mySrvMock;

  beforeEach(function() {
    mySrvMock = {
      method: function() {
        return 'value';
      }
    }
  });

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');
    inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      ctrl = $controller('mainCtrl', {
        $scop: scope,
        mySrv: mySrvMock
      });
    });
  });

  it('should return value', function() {
    expect(scope.callToMethod).toBe('value') // Pass
  });

  describe('Test 1.1', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      mySrvMock.method = function() {
        return 'different value';
      };
    });

    it('should return different value', function() {
      expect(scope.callToMethod).toBe('different value') // Fail (Expected 'value' to be 'different value')
    });
  });
});
```

There is a way to listen to the mock service changes?

Comment: That probably won't help, but sill - why don't you use [jasmine spies](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) to mock services behavior?

Comment: What does `scope.callToMethod` actually do?

Comment: I'm using spies for other methods for this one I just need to get a returned value. The `scope.callToMethod` is `$scope.callToMethod = mySrv.method()`

Comment: So the moment your controller is initialized, the `scope.callToMethod` is calculated? Then it makes sense that changing the `method` would not help - it's too late, controller was initialized, value was calculated. So either change the logic or initialize controller before each test

Comment: I see, so what should I do? I have other methods that invoked according to the return value of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

initialize controller before each it()

```
    describe('Test 1', function() {
  var ctrl, scope, mySrvMock, controllerFactory;

  beforeEach(function() {
    mySrvMock = {
      method: function() {
        return 'value';
      }
    }
  });

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('app');
    inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      controllerFactory = $controller.bind(this, 'mainCtrl',{
        $scop: scope,
        mySrv: mySrvMock
      }); 
      ctrl = controllerFactory();
    });
  });
describe('Test 2.1', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      ctrl = controllerFactory();
    });

  it('should return value', function() {
    expect(scope.callToMethod).toBe('value') // Pass
  });

});
  describe('Test 1.1', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      mySrvMock.method = function() {
        return 'different value';
      };
      ctrl = controllerFactory();
    });

    it('should return different value', function() {
      expect(scope.callToMethod).toBe('different value') // Fail (Expected 'value' to be 'different value')
    });
  });
});
```